# RabbitMQ connecting VM to Host

Tags: java, networking, rabbitmq

I'm new-ish to networking, and I'm swimming (drowning) in semantics.

I have a VM which runs a Java application.  Ideally, it would be fed inputs from the host through a RabbitMQ queue. The Java application would then place the results on another RabbitMQ queue on a different port where it will be used by the host application.  After researching it for a bit, it seems like RabbitMQ only exists in the localhost space with listeners on different ports, am I correct in this?

Do I need 2 RabbitMQ servers running in tandem, then, (one on the VM and other on Host) each listening to the same port?  Or do I just need one RabbitMQ server running while both applications are pointed to the same IP Address/Port?

Also, I have also read that you cannot connect as 'guest/guest' unless it is on localhost, which I understand, but how is RabbitMQ supposed to be configured/reachable to anything besides localhost?

I've been researching for several hours, but the documentation does not point to a direct answer/how-to guide. Perhaps it is my lack of network experience.  If anyone could elaborate on these questions or point me to some articles/helpful guides, I would be much obliged.

P.S. -- I don't even know what code to display to give context.  Let me know and I'll edit the code into the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RabbitMQ listens to TCP port 5672 on all network interfaces out-of-the-box. This includes the "loopback" interface (to allow fast connections to self) and interfaces visible to other remote hosts (including VMs).

For your use case, you probably need a single RabbitMQ instance for both directions. The application on the host will publish messages to one queue and the Java application in the VM will consume messages from that queue and push the result to a second queue. This second queue can be consumed by the application on the host.

For the user, you need to create a new user with the appropriate rights. This is documented in the [access control article](http://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html). To create the user, you can do it from the management web UI (after you enabled the management plugin) or using the `rabbitmqctl` command line tool.

The last part is networking between the host and the VM. It really depends on the technology you use. It may work out-of-the-box or you may have to configure how VMs are connected to the network. Refer to the documentation of your hypervisor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I found out that was grossly over complicating things.  While Rabbit 'lives' local host, it is still visible to the rest of the network.  All I had to do was modify the config file.

Also, the Rabbit-to-Rabbit setup also worked well for this usage case.

Thank you for your time and answer!

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer satisfies you, could you please accept it?

Comment: Certainly! My mistake for forgetting that.